# Atalho de teclado com javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando adicionar atalhos de teclado para selecionar botões de rádio, mas não está funcionando não manjo muito de javascript  então não sei se o erro está no código ou estou fazendo alguma referência errada a algum elemento do bootstrap. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> FREQUE </title>

    <!--css's-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //espera o documento carregar para executar o que nós queremos

            window.onload = function()
            {

                //no lugar do document, podemos utilizar qualquer outro elemento, mas utilizando o document podemos capturar o que o usuario digitar em qualquer lugar do documento
                document.onkeyup = function(e)
                {

                    //o "e" contém os dados do evento que foram disparados quando você apertou um botao do teu teclado
                    console.log(e.keyCode);//para saber qual o codigo do botão que foi apertado
                    /*
                        A : código 65
                        B : código 66
                        C : código 67
                        D : código 68
                        E : código 69
                        F : código 70
                        V : código 86
                    */
                    //pronto, ja sabemos quais são os codigos necessários
                    var elemento = null;//variavel que segura o elemento que vamos pegar
                    switch(e.which)
                    {

                        case 65 :
                            // 1 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('A');
                            break;
                        case 66 :
                            // 1 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('B');
                            break;
                        case 67 :
                            // 1 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('C');
                            break;
                        case 68 :
                            // 2 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('D');
                            break;
                        case 69 :
                            // 3 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('E');
                            break;
                        case 70 :
                            // 4 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('F');
                            break;
                        case 86 :
                            // 4 checkbox
                            elemento = document.getElementById('V');
                            break;
                        default :
                            //caso a tecla não seja a que nós queremos
                            return false;//para o script e espera o proximo botão que o usuário apertar
                            break;
                    }

                    //aqui ja temos o elemento, vamos ver se ele ja esta selecionado ou não
                    //eu só não entendi se vc quer habilitar/desabilitar ou selecionar/descelecionar o elemento, vou supor que seja selecionar/descelecionar
                    if(elemento.checked)
                    {

                        //elemento está selecionado, vamos desceleciona-lo
                        elemento.checked = false;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //elemento não está selecionado, vamos seleciona-lo
                        elemento.checked = true;

                    }


                }

            }

    </script

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-6">

   <div>
    </br>
    (FCC- Procurador do Estado - MT/ 2011) De acordo com a Constituição Federal, a atuação do Estado no dominio econômico 
a) restringe-se à atividade regulatória, vedada, em qualquer hipótese, a exploração direta de atividade econômica em regime de competição com o privado. 
b) engloba a atividade regulatória, fiscalizadora e de fomento, vedada a exploração direta de atividade comercial ou industrial. 
c) é exercida em caráter excepcional, restringindo-se às atividades que envolvam a s~gurança nacional. 
d) restringe-se à função normativa, reguladora e fiscalizadora e, apenas nos casos de relevante interesse  coletivo, à atividade de incentivo e planejamento. 
e) contempla, também, a exploração direta de atividade econômica, quando necessária aos imperativos da segurança nacional ou a relevante interesse coletivo, conforme definidos em lei.
    </br>
  </div>



        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

           <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="A" autocomplete="off"> A
          </label>

           <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="B" autocomplete="off"> B
          </label>

           <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="C" autocomplete="off"> C
          </label>

           <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="D" autocomplete="off"> D
          </label>

           <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="E" autocomplete="off"> E
          </label>

         </div>
        </br>
        </br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Responder</a>




      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " role="button" ><<</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " role="button" aria-pressed="true"><</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " role="button" aria-pressed="true">></a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " role="button" aria-pressed="true">>></a>

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="atalhos.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está correto. Ele está ativando o elemento corretamente, o fato de não está alterando a cor (para informar ao usuário) é que a classe "active" não está sendo aplicada no `label` do *input* ativo.

Abaixo deixo um exemplo comentado e refatorado.

**Exemplo:**

```js
window.onload = function() {

  document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  
    /* Captura o elemento através de uma função */
    var elemento = findElementbyShortcut(e.keyCode)
    
    /* Caso o elemento não seja encontado, sai da função */
    if (!elemento.length) return
    
    /* Remove a classe "active" do elemento ativo (caso haja) */
    $("#questions label").removeClass("active")

    /* Verifica se o elemento capturado está ativo */
    if (elemento.checked) {
      elemento.checked = false;
    } else {
      elemento.checked = true;
      
      /* Aplica a classe CSS para mudar a cor do elemento selecionado */
      $(elemento).parent().addClass("active")
    }
  }
}

/* Captura o elemento conforme o CharCode */
function findElementbyShortcut(keyCode) {
  return $(`#${String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toUpperCase()}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container" id="questions">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>(FCC- Procurador do Estado - MT/ 2011) De acordo com a Constituição Federal, a atuação do Estado no dominio econômico a) restringe-se à atividade regulatória, vedada, em qualquer hipótese, a exploração direta de atividade econômica em regime de competição
      com o privado. b) engloba a atividade regulatória, fiscalizadora e de fomento, vedada a exploração direta de atividade comercial ou industrial. c) é exercida em caráter excepcional, restringindo-se às atividades que envolvam a s~gurança nacional.
      d) restringe-se à função normativa, reguladora e fiscalizadora e, apenas nos casos de relevante interesse coletivo, à atividade de incentivo e planejamento. e) contempla, também, a exploração direta de atividade econômica, quando necessária aos
      imperativos da segurança nacional ou a relevante interesse coletivo, conforme definidos em lei.</p>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="A" autocomplete="off"> A
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="B" autocomplete="off"> B
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="C" autocomplete="off"> C
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="D" autocomplete="off"> D
      </label>

      <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" checked="" name="options" id="E" autocomplete="off"> E
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```